# In Excel, need cell to highlight if difference between two cells is greater than or less than 5

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have about 80k rows of data and I need to highlight anything where the difference is greater than *at least 5 either above or below it, like so.

- 45.0036
- 42.18393
- **42.93399**
- **59.47698**
- **110.91165**
- 113.56624

There are spaces in between some of the lines. Also is there any way to rotate the highlighted color every time it doesn't find one?

Comment: Weirdly enough, won't your condition mean that *all* the above items are highlighted? None of them have an exact difference of 5. Anyway, check my answer below. Would have been better if you detailed it more or showed us an attempt.

Comment: I'll try to edit in some more data.

I meant to imply that the difference is at least greater than or equal to 5

Comment: @simoco you are totally correct, I didn't catch that.

Comment: Also, another question. If a neighbor cell is empty, should it be read as `0` or remove it from the condition? Reason is, let's say you have these values: `15`-`10`-`Blank`. Focus on `10`. If `Blank` is treated as `0`, this will be highlighted since the difference will be 10, which will meet your requirement. If `Blank` is taken out, then `10` will not be highlighted as the difference is exactly 5.

Comment: @BK201, as I undersoot question, if you have `15-10-BLANK-3`, you should compare `10` and `3`

Comment: @BK201 remove it from the condition. Exactly 5 is meant to be highlighted as well but I didn't explain that properly. 2-4-7-12-22-1 would have 7, 12, 22, and 1 highlighted.

"if you have 15-10-BLANK-3, you should compare 10 and 3" Correct

Comment: Whew that makes it more difficult than I thought. Okay, will try to find a way. @simoco: You have an idea for the skip already, I take it?

Comment: @pnuts single spaces and possible negatives but unlikely. I haven't looked at every cell

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub HighlightLTGT5()

    Dim RngTarget As Range, Cell As Range
    Dim ColorIndex As Integer
    Dim DiffValOne As Double, DiffValTwo As Double

    Set RngTarget = Range("A1:A100000")
    ColorIndex = 4

    Start = Timer()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each Cell In RngTarget
        If Not IsEmpty(Cell) Then
            DiffValOne = Abs(Cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value - Cell.Value)
            DiffValTwo = Abs(Cell.Offset(1, 0).Value - Cell.Value)
            If DiffValOne <> 5 Or DiffValTwo <> 5 Then
                Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = ColorIndex
            Else
                Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = vbNone
            End If
        Else
            If ColorIndex = 4 Then
                ColorIndex = 3
            Else
                ColorIndex = 4
            End If
        End If
    Next Cell
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Debug.Print Timer() - Start

End Sub
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Let us know if this helps.

**EDIT:**

Takes about 4 seconds on my end to accommodate 100k rows.

[image]

Updated above code as well to include lines for showing runtime.

Comment: can you please show us timing for `about 80k rows`, just curious:)

Comment: @simoco: Lol, gladly. Be back in a moment.

Comment: Averages 4s on my end for 100k rows. Pretty decent, considering that it has so many `IF`s inside it. :D

Comment: good:) I think storing `Range("A1:A100000")` in array will inrease speed even more:)

Comment: Think so as well. Besides, this needs an overhaul as the condition is actually **`>=5`**. :)

Comment: @BK201 it seems to just turn the whole row red. I figure it's my mistake but I can't seem to figure it out.

It wasn't meant to be less than, I messed up while explaining it.

Comment: @andrewsmith1986, As I see, there is should be one change in code from `If DiffValOne <> 5 Or DiffValTwo <> 5 Then` to `If DiffValOne > 5 Or DiffValTwo > 5 Then`. But I think BK201 is already testing updated answer for new requirements:)

Comment: Use special variable for value of last non empty cell. Say A10 is non empty, than use `myVar=Range("A10") : myVarAddr=Range("A10").Address`. using loop skip all blank cells, (usign `If cell<>"" then .. else do nothing`). When you find next non empty cell, compare it's value with `myVar` (if greater 5), than highlight this cell and cell with addr `myVarAddr` too. Rewrite `myVar` and `myVarAddr`

Comment: As I'm almost out for the day from work, I will try continuing my answer for this at home. @simoco, I actually thought of a variation of that. What I did was create a dictionary, with the key being a simple iterator matching the row of the cell, and the element being the color index. This way, it's just a matter of iterating over the range and applying the color index of whatever's in the dictionary. However, it's a bit complicated to set up the above and below values so I'm continuing this at home. ;) If you get around to it, write yours. Very interested to see your approach!

Comment: there are good news for you `only single spaces` avaliable. That means that it's possible to have `10-blank-3`, but not `10-blank-blank-3`. You can create big formula with nested `IF`'s with `TRUE`/`FALSE` result, say, in last column and higlight only cells with result TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional formatting and `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`. That formula for cell A2 would be `=or(abs(a2-a1)>5,abs(a3-a2)>5)`, with the highlight as the format chosen.

Comment: I don't think "abs(a2-a1)>5" would be enough due to it needing to go in both directions.

Comment: @simoco Just tested it, it doesn't highlight both of the cells involved in the test. Thanks though for the suggestion.

Comment: the problem with this one is that it seems to stretch it out between 3 cells instead of just comparing the the neighbor.

Comment: @pnuts I meant that the formula seemed to spread the difference of 5 across three cells. I.e is a1=10, a2=12 and a3=14 they wouldn't be highlighted but if a3= 16, they would.